# The computed data do not change instantly when I change the data

Tags: vue.js

I have a Vue.js demo, look at bellow:

```
<template>
  <div class="index">

    <Row>
      <Select  v-for="(select, s_index) in select_data" v-model="selected_data_obj[s_index]" :key="'s-'+s_index" style="width:200px">
        <Option v-for="option in option_data[s_index]" :key="option.value" :value="option.value"></Option>
      </Select>

    </Row>

    <Row>
      <Button type="warning" @click="add_select_data">Add option</Button>
    </Row>
  </div>
</template>
<script>


  export default {
    data(){
      return {
        select_data:[{},{}],
        selected_data_obj : {

        },
//        option_data:  {
//          0: [{value:'a'}, {value:'b'}, {value:'c'}, {value:'d'}, {value:'e'}],
//          1: [{value:'a'}, {value:'b'}, {value:'c'}, {value:'d'}, {value:'e'}]
//        }
      }
    },
    computed: {
      option_data(){
        return {
          0: [{value:'a'}, {value:'b'}, {value:'c'}, {value:'d'}, {value:'e'}],
          1: [{value:'a'}, {value:'b'}, {value:'c'}, {value:'d'}, {value:'e'}]
        }
      }
    }
    ,
    methods: {
      add_select_data(){
        console.log('click')
        this.option_data["0"].push({value:'f'})
      }
    },

  };
</script>
```

I use the Add option button to add data for option_data.

I put the `option_data` in the computed method, but however if I click the `Add option`, it do not refresh the option, you see the bellow snapshot:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

But, if I put the `option_data` in the `data`, you see the component in my code. There won't have this issue.

How can I solve the issue? if I must put the `option_data` in the computed method?

Comment: Computed properties are used to compute some data and return It.A computed property will only re-evaluate when some of its dependencies have changed.The question is why you have to put options_data to the computed property ?

Comment: @BelminBedak Because in my case, the options_data is generated base on the props, so, I can not put it in the data.

Comment: Why you can't ? If the prop data is populated async, then you can try to watch that prop, and when change happens just assign them to the property in the `data`.Or you could use some of lifecycle hooks.
Hopefully I understood correctly your problem.

Comment: do you mean use the watch? when the base prop changed the options_data will change immediately?

Comment: You can add watcher for prop that you passed from parent component.In you `data()` you can declare `option_data` as empty object, and then in your wather, when change happens in prop, you just assign newValue data to the `option_data` in your `data()`.

Answer (score 0):

Computed properties are by default getter-only, so you should provide a setter.[More information about getter and setter](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Setter)

You can change your code here:

```js
export default {
    data(){
      return {
        select_data:[{},{}],
        selected_data_obj : {

        },
        option_data:  {
          0: [{value:'a'}, {value:'b'}, {value:'c'}, {value:'d'}, {value:'e'}],
          1: [{value:'a'}, {value:'b'}, {value:'c'}, {value:'d'}, {value:'e'}]
        }
      }
    },
    methods: {
      add_select_data(){
        console.log('click')
        this.option_data["0"].push({value:'f'})
      }
    },
  };
```